# How to set a default file name and a current directory in getSaveFileName dialog at the same time?

Tags: qt, qfiledialog

I read in this Qt reference http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#getSaveFileName about `getSaveFileName()` function in **qFileDialog**. In the third parameter `const QString & dir = QString()`, I can provide with a current directory or a default file name, but I don't know how to provide both **currentPath** and **ui->titleEdit->text().trimmed()** in `getSaveFileName()` function at the same time.

```
void TipManager::on_saveButton_clicked()
{
    //save dialog
    QString fileName = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this,
            tr("Save Tip Code"), currentPath /*ui->titleEdit->text().trimmed()*/,
            tr("Tip Code (*.txt);;All Files (*)"));
    saveFile(fileName);
}
```

**currentPath** is a current directory and **ui->titleEdit->text().trimmed()** is a default file name when I open a save dialog box.
How could I solve this?

@edit (solved)

I solved this question with a help of @thuga :

```
void TipManager::on_saveButton_clicked()
{
    //save dialog
    QString fileName = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this,
            tr("Save Tip Code"), currentPath +"/"+ ui->titleEdit->text().trimmed(),
            tr("Tip Code (*.txt);;All Files (*)"));
    saveFile(fileName);
}
```

I combined two **QString** variables with **+** and it seems that it is separated by **/**, so I put it in between two variables.

Comment: Just combine your path with the file name. Like in the code snippet shown in the docs.

Comment: @thuga I tried to type `currentPath | ui->titleEdit->text().trimmed()` and `currentPath & ui->titleEdit->text().trimmed()` but it didn't work. How should I type in?